# Cursor moves to the last character every time I try to edit the text in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have written a code so it can count the characters inside the text box. The countting is working as expected but the problem is every time i move the cursor any where in the text box to change a word or add a word as soon as i press the first character curor moves to the end of the text.

Could you please help me edit the code:

```
    function GetCountSms() {
    ConvertGreek();
    CounterSmsLen = $('#SndSms_Message').val().length;
    GetAlhpa($('#SndSms_Message').val());

    var i = 0;
    while (i < String(Two).length) {
        var oldindex = -1;
        while (String($('#SndSms_Message').val()).indexOf(String(String(Two).charAt(i)), oldindex) > -1) {
            //if ( String($('#SndSms_Message').val()).indexOf(String(String(Two).charAt(i))) > -1){
            CounterSmsLen += 1;
            oldindex = String($('#SndSms_Message').val()).indexOf(String(String(Two).charAt(i)), oldindex) + 1;


            console.log(i);
        }
        i++;

    }
    if ($('#SndSms_Message').val().length == 0)
        CounterSmsLen = 0;

    $('#SndSms_Count').html('  ' + CounterSmsLen + ' Characters' + UniCodestring + ' <br /> ' + Math.ceil(CounterSmsLen / Countsms) + '  Sms');
countsmsnumber=Math.ceil(CounterSmsLen / Countsms);
}
```

PS.

I have added few lines of codes into the above code (i have mention in the code which lines are new) and its working but the problem is the typing speed when i try to type something it takes more seconds to show than a normal typing. (its like when i stop typing computer still type for 3-4 seconds after i stop):

```
function GetCountSms() {

//NEW CODES PART 1

document.getElementById('SndSms_Message').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        var target = e.SndSms_Message,
            position = SndSms_Message.selectionStart;

//End OF NEW CODE



    ConvertGreek();
    CounterSmsLen = $('#SndSms_Message').val().length;
    GetAlhpa($('#SndSms_Message').val());

    var i = 0;
    while (i < String(Two).length) {
        var oldindex = -1;
        while (String($('#SndSms_Message').val()).indexOf(String(String(Two).charAt(i)), oldindex) > -1) {
            //if ( String($('#SndSms_Message').val()).indexOf(String(String(Two).charAt(i))) > -1){
            CounterSmsLen += 1;
            oldindex = String($('#SndSms_Message').val()).indexOf(String(String(Two).charAt(i)), oldindex) + 1;


            console.log(i);
        }
        i++;

    }

// NEW CODE PART 2
SndSms_Message.selectionEnd = position;    // Set the cursor back to the initial position.
    });
```

Comment: It looks rather complicated for just getting the number of characters inside a textbox. Especially when you already got the count with the line `CounterSmsLen = $('#SndSms_Message').val().length;`

Comment: yes its more complicated, cause some characters must be counted as 2. but overall what it does is counting characters.

Comment: The problem could also be in ConvertGreek() or GetAlhpa($('#SndSms_Message').val()). And where does 'Two' come from?